# App does not come up with http scheme

Tags: android, manifest, deep-linking

My manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ir.technovaa.offer">

    <application
        android:name=".OfferApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/offer_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.IntroductionActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.CallbackActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="offer.ir"
                    android:path="/refer"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

So, problem is in `CallbackActivity`, with the `http` scheme, `CallbackActivity` does not come up with a link, but if I change it to a custom scheme like `android:scheme="offer"` it works just fine and the activity will come up with the redirect link. So, what should I do for make `http` scheme works. Thank you.

Comment: are you redirecting  your app through https instead http??

Comment: No, I'm calling it exactly with http.

Comment: try replacing  path  to pathPrefix

Comment: In case of "http", is it opening the default browser? If so check by setting the intent priority (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)

Comment: remove slash in the last path

Comment: @sohanshetty I have tried both of your solutions before. No luck.

Comment: @Dinash I set priority with value of 999 and nothing changed.